# Outlook 2016 VBA Type Mismatch on Application.GetNamespace (after Windows update)

Tags: vba, outlook, windows-update, outlook-2016

I've had an Outlook 2016 VBA macro running for a year to check emails arriving in my inbox. Today, following installation of Windows 10 updates, I get a type mismatch error when this macro runs. The error line is the `Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")` line below:

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Inbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olRecip As Recipient
    Dim dt As String
    Dim strFile_Path As String

    dt = Format(CStr(Now), "yyyy_mmm_dd_hh_mm")
    strFile_Path = "d:\temp\parking.log"
    Open strFile_Path For Append As #1
    Write #1, dt & " " & "Application_Startup() triggered"
    Close #1


    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olRecip = olNs.CreateRecipient("me@gmail.com")
    Set Inbox = olNs.Folders("me@gmail.com").Folders("Inbox")
    Set Items = Inbox.Items
End Sub
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to make sure the COM references are set correctly.

[image]

You may try to run the code without setting a local variable:

```
Private Sub Application_Startup() 

 MsgBox "Welcome, " & Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").CurrentUser 

 Application.ActiveExplorer.WindowState = olMaximized 

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks - my References were also set exactly as per your image. I tried removing the explicit declaration of the Namespace variable (olNs), and that seems to work around the problem. Has the object type returned by Application.GetNameSpace changed?

Comment: Nothing has been changed so far. It seems your machine is corrupted a bit - windows registry keys were corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue (COM add-ins were fine) and as stated, removing the explicit declaration seems to fix the issue (you can also Dim the Namespace as an Object instead of Outlook.Namespace).

As a quick reference for anyone else I used the following code to bypass the issue:

```
With Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder: Set Inbox = .GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Dim Junk As Outlook.MAPIFolder: Set Junk = .GetDefaultFolder(olFolderJunk)
End With
```